# how do i create a test method for the method below?

Tags: java, testing

```
public static SearchResult getDatesFromRule(Rule rule, SearchResult searchResult) {
    if (Objects.nonNull(rule.getWhen()) && !rule.getWhen().getBundles().isEmpty()) {
        for (CriteriaBundle criteriaBundle : rule.getWhen().getBundles()) {
            if (criteriaBundle.getDescription().equals(WAYBILL_DATE_FACT_PROP)) {
                criteriaBundle.getCriterias().forEach(criteria -> {
                    if (criteria.getOperator().equals(Operator.GE)) {
                        searchResult.setEffectiveDate(RulesUtil.formatDate(criteria.getValue(), RCConstants.DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT,
                                RCConstants.UI_DATE_FORMAT));
                    } else if (criteria.getOperator().equals(Operator.LE)) {
                        searchResult.setExpirationDate(RulesUtil.formatDate(criteria.getValue(),
                                RCConstants.DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT, RCConstants.UI_DATE_FORMAT));
                    }
                });
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return searchResult;
}
```

Comment: Hi David! Welcome to Stack Overflow. It looks like your post is pretty much all code. Could you add some more details to help us understand what you've done and what you don't understand specifically?

Comment: Sorry, the code came out that way. It looked correct when i pasted it in. I want to create a test method that tests that method

Comment: IMHO that question isn't answerable in a meaningful way because it is not clear at all what all those involved instances and methods actually mean. For good tests you don't just need to test normal cases that will trigger all code paths, but also interesting edge cases.